# Sum attribute of object with Stream API

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I currently have the following situation:

I have got a `Report` object which can contain multiple `Query` objects. The `Query` objects have properties: `Optional<Filter> comparisonFilter`,  `Optional<String> filterChoice` and `int queryOutput`.

Not every query has a comparison filter, so I first check on that. Then, I make sure I get the queries for a particular filter (which is not the problem here, so I will not discuss this in detail). Every filter has some choices, of which the number of choices is variable.

Here is an example of the input (these `Query` objects all have the same comparisonFilter):

```
Query 1 -- Choice: 'First' -- Output: 10
Query 1 -- Choice: 'First' -- Output: 5
Query 1 -- Choice: 'Second' -- Output: 25
Query 1 -- Choice: 'Third' -- Output: 10
```

Now, I would like to sum the query outputs for every unique choice. I currently have this code:

```
report
.getQueries()
.stream()
.filter(q -> q.getComparisonFilter().isPresent())
.filter(q -> q.getComparisonFilter().get().equals(view.getFilter().get()))
.forEach(query -> {

    //Sum the query outputs per choice

});
```

I could do this by creating a `Map<String, Integer>`, where the key is the choice and the value is the query input. But then I would need to loop through the `Map` again to use the value for something (which is not important here).

The output should be like this:

```
Choice: 'First' -- Summed Output: 15
Choice: 'Second' -- Summed Output: 25
Choice: 'Third' -- Summed Output: 10
```

But I would like to use this 'Summed Output' directly in a `forEach` on the stream, but if this is not possible or practical anymore, I am okay with that.

I would like to do this the 'Java 8'-way, but I can not seem to find out how.

So my question is: **Is it possible to do this shorter with the new Stream API?**

Note: If anyone has some ideas about how I could make this question more general (maybe a better title and some generalizations), please let me know!

Comment: It sounds as if you have this problem: http://www.leveluplunch.com/java/examples/java-util-stream-groupingBy-example/

Comment: Thanks for your comment @LutzHorn, it is a very helpful link. I get the `groupingBy` method, and then I could stream the `keySet`, but is it then also possible to sum the `queryInput` for every choice from within the stream? Maybe some reduction is possible?

Comment: @bashoogzaad I'm not sure I get what do you want to do; especially the use of `Optional<String> filterChoice`. Do you want to sum the queries from the value in this optional or from the values in the optional which contains the Filter? Is it possible to have an example of input/output?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If I understand well, you are indeed looking for a `groupingBy` and then you have to group the values by summing their int property.

The `groupingBy` will give you a `Map<String, List<Query>>` but then the downstream collector (`Collectors.summingInt` in this case) will sum all the `int` values of the `Query` instances in the list, resulting in a `Map<String, Integer>`.

```
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.groupingBy;
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.summingInt;
...

Map<String, Integer> map = 
    report.getQueries()
          .stream()
          .filter(q -> q.getComparisonFilter().isPresent())
          .filter(q -> q.getComparisonFilter().get().equals(view.getFilter().get()))
          .collect(groupingBy(q -> q.filterChoice.get(), summingInt(q -> q.queryOutput)));
```

Note that you should check whether the `filterChoice` Optional is not empty (maybe add another `filter` clause?). You can see this small [gist](https://gist.github.com/alexcrt/9cf93fb2c83a451abc77) for a basic and simplified demo to illustrate the principle.

Also the `Optional` class provide a sensible implementation of `equals` so the filter clause could looks like this:

```
.filter(q -> q.getComparisonFilter().equals(view.getFilter()))
```

Comment: Thanks for you great answer! It seems to work in the gist, but I get an error that `Map<String, Double>` can not be cast to `Map<Object, Double>`. I think it has something to do with my code, but the filterChoice is just a `Optional<String>`. I wil try to figure this out, and accept your answer.

Comment: @bashoogzaad Do you compile with Eclipse or Javac? Eclipse compiler has still some troubles with type inference (and with some Java 8 features in general). Try to compile it with javac. If it doesn't compile; either you made an error or you would have to help the compiler by providing the type ;-)

Comment: I am using Eclipse compiler so that could be the problem. I will look into my code some further, but I think it is just my mistake somewhere. Now Eclipse even says: cannot convert `Map<String, Double>` to `Map<String, Double>`