# Sum up fields based on another field in a stream

Tags: java, stream, java-8, grouping

I have a List of objects that look like this:

```
{
    value=500
    category="GROCERY"
},
{
    value=300
    category="GROCERY"
},
{
    value=100
    category="FUEL"
},
{
    value=300
    category="SMALL APPLIANCE REPAIR"
},
{
    value=200
    category="FUEL"
}
```

I would like to transform that into a List of objects that looks like this:

```
{
    value=800
    category="GROCERY"
},
{
    value=300
    category="FUEL"
},
{
    value=300
    category="SMALL APPLIANCE REPAIR"
}
```

Basically add up all the values with the same category.

Should I be using flatMap? Reduce? I don't understand the nuances of these to figure it out.

Help?

EDIT:

There are close duplicates of this question:
[Is there an aggregateBy method in the stream Java 8 api?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23848129/is-there-an-aggregateby-method-in-the-stream-java-8-api)
and
[Sum attribute of object with Stream API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28586186/sum-attribute-of-object-with-stream-api)

But in both cases, the end result is a map, not a list

The final solution I used, based on answers by @AndrewTobilko and @JBNizet was:

```
List<MyClass> myClassList = list.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(YourClass::getCategory,
                    Collectors.summingInt(YourClass::getValue)))
    .entrySet().stream().map(e -> new MyClass(e.getKey(), e.getValue()).collect(toList());
```

Comment: @AndrewTobilko you answer looked correct to me. Why did you delete it?

Comment: Yes, I caught it and it works fine! Why did you delete it? The only issue (which I can live with) is that I get a Map<category, value> returned.

Comment: Just append `.entrySet().stream().map(e -> new YourClass(e.getKey(), e.getValue()).collect(toList());`

Comment: Also refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28586186/sum-attribute-of-object-with-stream-ap

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With static import of the `Collectors` class:

```
list.stream().collect(groupingBy(Class::getCategory, summingInt(Class::getValue)));
```

You will get a map `Map<String, Integer>`. `Class` has to have `getValue` and `getCategory` methods to write method references, something like

```
public class Class {
    private String category;
    private int value;

    public String getCategory() { return category; }
    public int getValue() { return value; }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

The Collectors class provides a 'groupingBy' that allows you to perform a 'group by' operation on a stream (similar behavior like GROUP BY in databases). Under the assumption that your list of objects is of type 'Objects', the following code should work:

```
Map<String, Integer> valueByCategory = myObjects.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(MyObjects::getCategory, Collectors.summingInt(MyObjects::getValue)));
```

The code basically groups your stream by each category and runs a Collector on each group that sums up the return value of getValue() of every stream element.
See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html

Comment: Thanks Christian. I up voted your answer but accepted Andrew's because he replied first (then deleted, and reposted!)

Answer (score 0):

Reduce-based method:

```
List<Obj> values = list.stream().collect(
        Collectors.groupingBy(Obj::getCategory, Collectors.reducing((a, b) -> new Obj(a.getValue() + b.getValue(), a.getCategory())))
).values().stream().map(Optional::get).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Bad thing is secondary `stream()` call to remap result from `Optional<Obj>` and intermediate `Map<String, Optional<Obj>>` object.

I can suggest alternative variant (less readable) using sorting:

```
List<Obj> values2 = list.stream()
    .sorted((o1, o2) -> o1.getCategory().compareTo(o2.getCategory()))
    .collect(
        LinkedList<Obj>::new,
        (ll, obj) -> {
            Obj last = null;
            if(!ll.isEmpty()) {
                last = ll.getLast();
            }

            if (last == null || !last.getCategory().equals(obj.getCategory())) {
                ll.add(new Obj(obj.getValue(), obj.getCategory())); //deep copy here
            } else {
                last.setValue(last.getValue() + obj.getValue());
            }
        },
        (list1, list2) -> {
              //for parallel execution do a simple merge join here
              throw new RuntimeException("parallel evaluation not supported"); 
         }
    );
```

Here we sort list of `Obj`s by category and then processing it sequentially, squashing consecutive objects from same category.

Unfortunately, there is no method in Java to do it without manually keeping last element or elements list (see also [Collect successive pairs from a stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20470010/collect-successive-pairs-from-a-stream))

Working example with both snippets can be checked here: https://ideone.com/p3bKV8

Comment: `summingInt` is more straightforward (and efficient) than using `reduce`.

Comment: @BrianGoetz ... can't argue with that. Just focused on keep the data structure and missed transforming to `Map<String, Integer>` variant. What could you say about the second method? Can sorting and consecutive summing be more effective that `grouping`+`summingInt` (sort-based approach compared to hash-based)?

Comment: @Nikolay Sorting + summing can only be faster, iff the hashbased collection need `O(n)` for lookup. If there is a proper hash function - and there is - then the lookup needs `O(1)` which answers your question.

Comment: **UPD:** removed excessive qualifiers from answer due to comments.